# Error message "service cloudbuilt.googleapis.com is not for consumer..." when deploying App Engine application

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment, google-cloud-platform, google-earth

My team and I are working on the Trendy Lights Tutorial.

We have set up all the files and also have converted the .p12 key to .pem key but failed to run the app on the Google Cloud Platform and constantly got the error message saying:

> You do not have permission to access project [...] and service
>   "cloudbuilt.googleapis.com" is not for consumer..."

[image: Picture: Error in Google Cloud Platform]

We have already whitelisted our service account for the use of Earth Engine. Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? If deploying using a service account you need to a) grant project Owner permissions to deploy and b) use 'gcloud auth activate-service-account' on the exported service account key before running 'gcloud app deploy'.

Answer (score 4):

I see that you are attempting to deploy your application to the [App Engine Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/).

The Flexible environment differs from the Standard environment in that it gives you more control over the individual instances that are running your deployed application. It does this by hosting your application within Docker on [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/) virtual machines.

Therefore, you will need to enable the [Compute Engine API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/compute_component/overview) for your project so that the GCloud tool can start new Compute Engine virtual machines when you deploy your application.

Note: Since the Flexible environment uses [Compute Engine resources](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#costs-for-flexible-environment-instances), you will also need to [enable billing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/#billing) for your project.

---

If after performing the above you still experience the 'cloudbuild.googleapis.com' error, I ask that you run `gcloud components update`, then ensure that the value of **account** seen in the output of the command `gcloud info` has [Owner or Editor permissions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access#changing_team_members_access) in your project.

---

If it still persists after all of the above, you should then open a [Public Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry) to inform our backend team of the issue.