# unknown: Service 'containerregistry.googleapis.com' is not enabled for consumer 'project:next'

Tags: reactjs, docker, google-cloud-platform, next.js

I had dockerized my Next.js app, and was trying to deploy it to google cloud, but while pushing the docker image to the registry, I encountered this error.

> unknown: Service 'containerregistry.googleapis.com' is not enabled for consumer 'project:next'

I had enabled this API for all the possible projects, but it keeps retrying.

The command I am using was

```
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/next/helloworld --project next-317511
```

Comment: Do you have billing enabled?

Comment: According to GCP's Container Registry documentation, when you encounter `Registry API is disabled` again and again, then you should check for spelling errors in your hostname, project ID, image name, and tag or digest. Here's the link https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/troubleshooting#error_status_405_v1_registry_api_is_disabled

Comment: You can also have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40710526/error-message-service-cloudbuilt-googleapis-com-is-not-for-consumer-when-de
It's not a direct answer to your problem but you can solve your problem using it as a reference.

Answer (score 7):

As referred in the comments from @John Hanley and @Yogesh. I’ll summarize a possible troubleshooting that you can follow in order to solve your issue:

1. Check that Billing is [enabled](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/console#billing) for the particular project where I you were trying to have the container.
2. Ensure that your hostname, project ID, image name, and tag or digest are spelled correctly as stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/troubleshooting#error_status_405_v1_registry_api_is_disabled).
3. Enable API link [here](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/containerregistry.googleapis.com) to enable the container registry API and see if you got a successful message for the particular project (Container Registry API has been enabled.)
4. If it still doesn't work, please disable the API and enable it again.
5. Delete the image with this command and try it again.

> gcloud container images delete [image] --force-delete-tags

5. As an extra information, check [Granting IAM permissions](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control#grant) in order to know how to manage permissions in Cloud Storage buckets. You would need to have permissions in the Storage Admin role.
   Also, the [QuickStart](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/quickstart) of container registry could help for pushing and pulling the images to the Container Registry.